# Is it possible to add custom view on DefaultTimeBar in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

Need to add custom views on the DefaultTimeBar in Exoplayer at particular timestamps to indicate that there is something which is coming up during the video play similar to what we have in terms of video ads.

Please find the attached image to understand the exact requirement.[image: Exoplayer DefaultTimeBar]